# Generate access token based on group in Microsoft Azure Active Directory External Identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

We are designing a web application and want to use Azure AD External Identities.
We define Multiple clients in our web application, and each client can have multiple users. A client invites users and gives them access to data by their email addresses, which could be personal or organizational.

Users log in to the application. After the login, if they have access to multiple clients (because different clients can invite them), they should be able to switch between clients and get an access token for the selected client.

It is essential to mention that each user has different permission on different clients; for example, a user can have admin permissions in one client and simple user permissions in another.

Is it possible to have these features in Azure AD?
How should We use Group, Scope, and Role to implement it?

Comment: I think your requirement can be realized by ADD and I suggest you reviewing [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/enable-webapp-signin/?view=aspnetcore-7.0): you might want to restrict part of the application depending on the user having a role in the application or belonging to a group.....

Answer (score 0):

Whenever external identity providers (**azure ad** in this case) are used in 3rd party application:

- It's `scope` which defines permissions. It can be specified at ***client(application)*** level. Hence Whatever scope you define for a particular client it would apply to all users. Obviously You can create multiple applications which contains different `scope`.
- `roles`,`groups` has nothing to do with generating access tokens since those are used only when you login into azure portal.
- Here You will have to use `client credentials flow` of OAuth 2.0. Otherwise user will need to login each time if `auth code flow` is used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please elaborate on the details? Because I am a beginner in Azure.

Comment: You will need to understand the basic before implementation. You can have a look at the terminologies on this OAuth documentation. 1)  https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/scope/   2) https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/

Comment: Thank you for sharing these links, I know the meaning of scopes, but it is not clear to me how to use them to give permission to the clients based on the description in the question.
It will be appreciated if you provide me with an example.